# WebRTC many to many, how to identify user?

Tags: webrtc

User started with DataChannel only.

AudioChannel is added through renegotiation later.

```
var mLocalAudio;
navigator.getUserMedia({ video: false, audio: true },
    function (myStream) {
        mLocalAudio = myStream;
        mConn.addStream(myStream);
    }, function (e) { });
```

On the remote peer, `ontrack` will be triggered and we add the stream on to an `<audio>` element.

But since this is a many to many connection, there will have multiple peers trying to swith on / off their audio channel from time to time.

My problem is, how can I identify which audio track is belongs to which user?

Comment: By which peer connection `ontrack` is fired on maybe?

Comment: Yes, I have figured that out, ontrack need to add a userid to the element where the stream is attached to.